# Modify SQL Server database to support russian data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, unicode, character-encoding, multibyte

I am currently modifying a SQL Server 2008 database to support different data that needs to support multi-byte character sets eg russian. I am converting all `varchar` columns to `nvarchar` etc. I am wondering if I need to carry out any other actions to ensure the SQL Server database will support russian data?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchnage.com may be a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Server-Side Programming with Unicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191313%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). It's short and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

If any of your Varchar fields had a `DEFAULT ''` set, this should be changed to `DEFAULT N''` when you change them to NVarchar